# Angular 5 Provide http interceptor based on environment

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-http-interceptors

I have the following two environments in my angular-cli (v1.5.1, angular v5) application:

1. dev
2. prod

Dev makes use of mock data, which I provide with an http-interceptor.
Pro makes use of a live rest api.

How do I provide the http-interceptor on dev, but not on pro?
I already tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
{
  provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
  useFactory: () => {
    if (environment.useMockBackend === true) {
      return MockHttpInterceptor;
    }
    return false;
  },
  multi: true
}
```

Answer (score 8):

In my Angular 5.2 project I used following approach.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { MyInterceptor } from './my.interceptor';

const commonProviders = [/*...*/];
const nonProductionProviders = [{ 
  provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
  useClass: MyInterceptor,
  multi: true
}];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    // ...
  ],
  providers: [
    ...commonProviders,
    ...!environment.production ? nonProductionProviders : []
  ]
})
```

**my.interceptor.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpRequest, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class MyInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    // ...
    return next.handle(req);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I've come up with the following approach (this is in Angular 7), by drawing on the previous answers from @dhilt and @kemsky:

**Your dev environment file**

```
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MyDevInterceptor} from './my-dev.interceptor';

export const ENVIRONMENT_SPECIFIC_PROVIDERS = [
  { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: MyDevInterceptor, multi: true }
];
```

**environment.prod.ts**

```
export const ENVIRONMENT_SPECIFIC_PROVIDERS = [];
```

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [
    ENVIRONMENT_SPECIFIC_PROVIDERS
  ]
})
```

It's simple, it works a treat, and it means that your code base contains no references to anything that's not required by your environment.

Comment: I have specified some constants in the environment that are used in HttpInterceptor and it causes Circular dependency warning when I implement as in your example

Comment: Guess you'll need to find somewhere else to put those constants then @NuryagdyMustapayev! :-)

Or use a different approach...

Comment: @DanKing so ENVIRONMENT_SPECIFIC_PROVIDERS in app.module.ts should be imported from environment.ts or environment.prod.ts?

Comment: @MitulPanchal You never import `environment.prod.ts` directly - you always import `environment.ts`.  This is then substituted at build time according to the configuration in your `angular.json` file. See https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-application-environments

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to export interceptor providers from environment file, prod environment exports do-nothing interceptor or just any other dummy provider (lets name it `DefaultHttpInterceptor`) and dev exports `MockHttpInterceptor`.

dev environment: `export const INTERCEPTORS = {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, ... MockHttpInterceptor}`

prod environment: `export const INTERCEPTORS = {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, ... DefaultHttpInterceptor}`

Then you can use it like usual:

```
import { INTERCEPTORS } from './../environments/environment';
@NgModule({
providers      : [
        ...
        INTERCEPTORS 
        ...
    ]
...
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I get the following error:

`ERROR TypeError: this.interceptor.intercept is not a function`

Comment: Maybe it should be `return new MockHttpInterceptor();`?